# Type mismatch, expected util.List[Nothing] from java to scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to learn Scala and am running into some trouble working with lists. I run into :

```
Type mismatch, expected util.List[Nothing], actual ArrayList[Role]
```

from this portion of my scala code

```
val roleList = {
    val singleRoleList = new util.ArrayList[Role]
    singleRoleList.add(mockRole)
    singleRoleList
}

listResult.setItems(roleList)
```

where listResult's class is defined as such in java code

```
public class ListResult<M> {
    /**
     * Result items.
     */
    private List<M> items;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public ListResult() {

    }
    /**
     * Gets items from list request.
     * @return List of items.
     */
    public List<M> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    /**
     * Sets items for list request.
     * @param items the items to set
     */
    public void setItems(final List<M> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

seems like an issue with java/scala and am not too sure how to approach this. Any tips?

Comment: How is `listResult` itself defined? E.g. `val listResult = new ListResult()`?

Comment: yes that is exactly how it is defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong type for `listResult`.

```
val listResult = new ListResult()
```

forces the compiler to infer the type parameter as [`Nothing`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Nothing.html), because it can't do any better. You need e.g.

```
val listResult = new ListResult[Role]()
```

or

```
val listResult: ListResult[Role] = new ListResult()
```

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should be `[Role]` of course.